# Unable to login into Titanium Studio

Tags: authentication, titanium-studio

I am using still titanium studio till last year I was able to login, but when I tried to login today (Fed, 2016) I am facing an login issue. When I try to login to Titanium studio it is throwing "The login server returned an error. Please consult the troubleshooting page for more information". I am able to login using terminal. Till last year I was able to login and I have not updated any thing recently.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here. Seems like they have taken down the authentication service.